# Переменная как параметр другой переменной

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть переменная `$field1["Field"]`, в которой хранится название поля базы данных. И есть переменная `$row[]`, которая выводит указанное поле. Мне нужно вытащить из `$field1["Field"]` текстовую строку и подставить ее в `$row[]`. В общем, как корректно сделать что-то вроде `echo $row['.$field1["Field"].']`?

Comment: ну `$row[$field1["Field"]]` же

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так и вытаскивайте

```
echo $row[$field1["Field"]]
```

Comment: о, боже! не знал, что все так элементарно.

Answer (score -1):

Не уверен, что правильно, но попробуй так:

```
echo $row[(string)$field1['Field']]
```

или

```
echo $row["$field1['Field']"]
```